# Return values from different xml files in FLWOR expression

Tags: xquery, flwor

I want to return different values from different Collections in one FLWOR expression.

The xml files are:

productos.xml

```
<productos>
<product categoria="A" pvp="20">
    <codigo>A2015</codigo>
    <nombre>Cuchillas</nombre>
    <stock>100</stock>
</product>
<product categoria="A" pvp="5">
    <codigo>A2005</codigo>
    <nombre>Laminas</nombre>
    <stock>57</stock>
</product>
<product categoria="B" pvp="15">
    <codigo>B1501</codigo>
    <nombre>Comida</nombre>
    <stock>50</stock>
</product>
</productos>
```

clientes.xml

```
<clientes>
<clien numero="01">
    <nombre>Luu</nombre>
    <poblacion>Madrid</poblacion>
    <tlf>111111111</tlf>
    <direccion>Alcala</direccion>
</clien>
<clien numero="02">
    <nombre>Joan</nombre>
    <poblacion>Barcelona</poblacion>
    <tlf>2222222222</tlf>
    <direccion>Canalets</direccion>
</clien>
</clientes>
```

facturas.xml

```
<facturas>
<factura numero="100">
    <fecha>01/01/01</fecha>
    <importe>25</importe>
    <numcliente>01</numcliente>
</factura>
<factura numero="101">
    <fecha>01/01/01</fecha>
    <importe>40</importe>
    <numcliente>01</numcliente>
</factura>
<factura numero="102">
    <fecha>01/01/01</fecha>
    <importe>4</importe>
    <numcliente>02</numcliente>
</factura>
</facturas>
```

detallefacturas.xml

```
<detallefacturas>
<factura numero="100">
    <codigo>Z</codigo>
    <producto descuento="0">
        <codigo>A2015</codigo>
        <unidades>2</unidades>
    </producto>
    <producto descuento="0">
        <codigo>A2005</codigo>
        <unidades>1</unidades>
    </producto>
</factura>
<factura numero="101">
    <codigo>X</codigo>
    <producto descuento="0">
        <codigo>B1501</codigo>
        <unidades>5</unidades>
    </producto>
</factura>
<factura numero="102">
    <codigo>Y</codigo>
    <producto descuento="0">
        <codigo>C2020</codigo>
        <unidades>15</unidades>
    </producto>
    <producto descuento="0">
        <codigo>A2015</codigo>
        <unidades>2</unidades>
    </producto>
</factura>
</detallefacturas>
```

I need to return the details of "facturas" that contains products with "categoria=A"

This could be a result:

Num factura 100, cliente Luu, Products categoria A: 2

I am triying to do something similar to a JOIN in SQL but i can not get the values I need.

EDIT:

That is what I got for now, but it does not work.

```
for $x in collection("/ventas")
let $NUMFACTURA := $x/facturas/factura
let $NOM := $x/clientes/clien[@numero=$NUMFACTURA/numcliente]
let $PRODFACTURA := $x/detallefacturas/factura[@numero=$NUMFACTURA/@numero]
let $CODPRODATA := $x/productos/product[@categoria="A"]/codigo
return $NUMFACTURA/@numero/string()
```

Comment: Could you include your current attempt ? No need to explain you how to use `doc(path)` if you already know about it, etc.

Comment: I have deleted my others attempts, but now I am triying to get the differents values using "let". In one "let" I get the products with categoria="A", in the next "let" I try to get details from "detallefacturas.xml" where "producto/codigo" equals the values saved on the first let. I do not know if it will works but i do not know what to try...

Comment: How does your current query look like?

Comment: I edited and added my current attemp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the XQuery 3.1

```
let $productosA := $documento-productos/productos/product[@categoria = $categoria]
for $factura in facturas/factura
let $factura-detalle := $documento-detalles-de-facturas/detallefacturas/factura[@numero = $factura/@numero],
    $cliente := $documento-clientes/clientes/clien[@numero = $factura/numcliente],
    $factura-productosA := $factura-detalle/producto[codigo = $productosA/codigo]
where (not(empty($factura-productosA)))
return 
    ``[Num factura `{$factura/@numero}`, cliente `{$cliente/nombre}`, Products categoria A: `{count($factura-productosA)}`]``
```

for your sample data I get the result

```
Num factura 100, cliente Luu, Products categoria A: 2
Num factura 102, cliente Joan, Products categoria A: 1
```

Full query with a primary input document of the facturas and, for the example, the other documents being set up as inline variables which you could of course replace with `doc` or `collection` calls, is as follows:

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'text';
declare option output:item-separator '&#10;';

declare variable $categoria as xs:string := 'A';

declare variable $documento-productos as document-node(element(productos)) := document {
    <productos>
    <product categoria="A" pvp="20">
        <codigo>A2015</codigo>
        <nombre>Cuchillas</nombre>
        <stock>100</stock>
    </product>
    <product categoria="A" pvp="5">
        <codigo>A2005</codigo>
        <nombre>Laminas</nombre>
        <stock>57</stock>
    </product>
    <product categoria="B" pvp="15">
        <codigo>B1501</codigo>
        <nombre>Comida</nombre>
        <stock>50</stock>
    </product>
    </productos>
};

declare variable $documento-clientes as document-node(element(clientes)) := document {
    <clientes>
    <clien numero="01">
        <nombre>Luu</nombre>
        <poblacion>Madrid</poblacion>
        <tlf>111111111</tlf>
        <direccion>Alcala</direccion>
    </clien>
    <clien numero="02">
        <nombre>Joan</nombre>
        <poblacion>Barcelona</poblacion>
        <tlf>2222222222</tlf>
        <direccion>Canalets</direccion>
    </clien>
    </clientes>
};

declare variable $documento-detalles-de-facturas as document-node(element(detallefacturas)) := document {
    <detallefacturas>
    <factura numero="100">
        <codigo>Z</codigo>
        <producto descuento="0">
            <codigo>A2015</codigo>
            <unidades>2</unidades>
        </producto>
        <producto descuento="0">
            <codigo>A2005</codigo>
            <unidades>1</unidades>
        </producto>
    </factura>
    <factura numero="101">
        <codigo>X</codigo>
        <producto descuento="0">
            <codigo>B1501</codigo>
            <unidades>5</unidades>
        </producto>
    </factura>
    <factura numero="102">
        <codigo>Y</codigo>
        <producto descuento="0">
            <codigo>C2020</codigo>
            <unidades>15</unidades>
        </producto>
        <producto descuento="0">
            <codigo>A2015</codigo>
            <unidades>2</unidades>
        </producto>
    </factura>
    </detallefacturas>
};

let $productosA := $documento-productos/productos/product[@categoria = $categoria]
for $factura in facturas/factura
let $factura-detalle := $documento-detalles-de-facturas/detallefacturas/factura[@numero = $factura/@numero],
    $cliente := $documento-clientes/clientes/clien[@numero = $factura/numcliente],
    $factura-productosA := $factura-detalle/producto[codigo = $productosA/codigo]
where (not(empty($factura-productosA)))
return 
    ``[Num factura `{$factura/@numero}`, cliente `{$cliente/nombre}`, Products categoria A: `{count($factura-productosA)}`]``
```

Online sample at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e29/2.